# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined// detect undefined

Tags: javascript, foreach, undefined, typeerror

what am I doing wrong?
need to detect the issue here.

```
function showQuestion(question) {
    questionElement.innerText = question.question
    question.answers.forEach(answer => {
        const button = document.createElement('button')
        button.innerText = answer.text
        button.classList.add('btn')
        if (answer.correct) {
            button.dataset.correct = answer.correct
        }
        button.addEventListener('click', selectAnswer)
        answerButtonsElement.appendChild(button)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved
Misspelt answer object and was looping over a correct spelling of answer.....

God.....Javascript!!!